# Why am I unable to run this iOS example project in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

That library includes an example. When I open the example project, "Run" is greyed out under the Product menu. If I switch the scheme to the last one, it crashes with a clang error.

I'm running the Xcode 5.1 DP1, is that why?

Comment: Can you run it on Xcode 5.0.2?

Comment: The demo project for this library appears to be broken.  I can't run it in Xcode 5.0.2 because webp can't be found.  You should open an issue for the developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to git clone the project with its submodule: git clone --recursive…

Do not use the "download source code" feature of Github as it doesn't retrieve project dependencies for you. You may also disable WebP by linking the demo project with "SDWebImage" target instead of "SDWebImage+WebP".